# regex match repeating variable pattern

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have a document which contains following numbering bullets:

```
PLAN: 

1.  Make tea.                                                                                                                                
2.  Make coffe.                                                                                                                      
3.  Goto the market.
```

I use this regex `\:\s+(\d\.\s+[\w \.]+){1,9}` to capture and extract the bulletted lists in a file. However it only matches the first bullet point. There can be from 2-7 bullet points per listing, I intend that `(\d\.\s+[\w \.]+){1,9}` should allow to match repeating bullet points but it does not.

So how can I extract only bulleted list of above format using regex?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/AeNvQA/1. Also, try `:((?:\s*\d\..+)+)`

Comment: With global flag `g` your snippet `(\d\.\s+[\w \.]+){1,9}` is working great: [https://regex101.com/r/AeNvQA/3](https://regex101.com/r/AeNvQA/3)
without matches only the first bullet.

Answer (score 0):

You may quantify the single bullet pattern and wrap it with an outer capturing group:

```
:\s*((?:\s*\d+\.\s+.+)+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AeNvQA/5)

**Details**:

- `:\s*` - a colon and then 0+ whitespaces
- `((?:\s*\d+\.\s+.+)+)` - Group 1 capturing a sequence of 1 or more sequences of:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `.+` - any 1+ chars other than line break chars (depends on the regex flavor actually and flags/modifiers you pass)